# How to force Entity Framework 6 to generate parameters of equivalent size to their corresponding database columns

Tags: entity-framework-6, always-encrypted

I've created a database-first EDM for a table with columns encrypted using Always Encrypted. Our business prohibits direct access to tables, so I'm also using stored procedures for all database access.

When I try to insert row, I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Operand type clash: varchar(8000)
>   encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED',
>   encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',
>   column_encryption_key_name = 'XXXXXX',
>   column_encryption_key_database_name = 'XXXXXX') collation_name =
>   'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' is incompatible with varchar(60)
>   encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED',
>   encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',
>   column_encryption_key_name = 'XXXXXX',
>   column_encryption_key_database_name = 'XXXXXX') collation_name =
>   'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

The stored procedure parameter is declared as varchar(60) which matches the table definition.

Because I'm using Always Encrypted, the parameter definition must match the column definition. However, EF generates a parameter declared as varchar(8000) for this property, which violates the encryption contract.

Is there any way to force EF to use the declared parameter length?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, see description [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2f9872cf-b0ff-4fbc-9599-6dc96f9fee09/how-to-force-entity-framework-6-to-generate-parameters-of-equivalent-size-to-their-corresponding?forum=adodotnetentityframework). In this particular scenario, the EDM contains two definitions of the stored procedure: one in the StorageModels element and one in the ConceptualModels element. Setting the MaxLength attribute in the StorageModels definition resolves the problem.